# xmlReadMemory - unknown 'url' parameter

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, libxml2

I have my `xml` as `char buffer` (that's fetched from server, I don't want to save it -> takes extra time and is completely obsolete):

```
char myword[] = "...xml..."
xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(xsdFilePath);
xmlDocPtr doc = ?;
```

Now I need to get `doc`. I'm trying to use following function:

```
doc = xmlReadMemory(myword, sizeof(myword), ?URL?, NULL, 0)
```

But the problem is with `URL`, what should I put in there..? Am I using this function right? Maybe there is another way to get `xmlDocPtr`?

BTW: I need `xmlDocPtr` to perform:

```
ret = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(ctxt, doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass a `NULL` pointer:

```
doc = xmlReadMemory(myword, sizeof(myword), NULL, NULL, 0);
```